# How to read data by category in to separate varibales

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
dataFileName='RFInput.xlsx'
sheetName='Rawdata'
sheetNamePara='paraList'
dataRaw=pd.read_excel(dataFileName, sheetname = sheetName)
datapara=pd.read_excel(dataFileName, sheetname = sheetNamePara)

noData=len(dataRaw)
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


labels = datapara
x = dataRaw[labels]
y = dataRaw['classVariable']
```

In RFInput.xlsx, sheetname="paraList", I have list of parameters whose data I need to extract from Rawdata. In paraList, the first row is names of the variables, and in 2nd row, I marked category of each variable as either Y or N. I want to read Y category variables data into x_Y, and N category variables data in to x_N.

```
classVariable   Category    Group Category.pare Status.dist
N                 N                Y               N
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Which line? What does the error say?

Comment: How to separate the variables by its category (N or Y). then extract data of N type variables in to x_N, Y type variables data in to x_Y. I dont know how to separate them,

Comment: Can you show me first 10 records from `dataRaw` and `datapara`? Refer to [MCVE] to better understand what I am asking for.

Comment: This is not helping at all. try to [.head()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) and I do not see 4 col and 2 rows in your question.